# Uniform amenability at infinity

Tags: gr.group-theory, geometric-group-theory, free-groups, amenability

Let's recall that a group $G$ is amenable if for any finite subset $E\subset G$ and any $\epsilon>0$
there is a finite subset $F\subset G$ such that
$$\max_{s\in E} |s F \mathbin{\triangle} F| \le \epsilon |F|.$$
The group $G$ is said to be **uniformly amenable** if one can find such $F$
with $|F|\le \alpha(|E|,\epsilon)$ for some $\alpha(m,t)$, i.e., the size of $F$ can be bound in terms of $|E|$ and $\epsilon$.
See [Bozejko's paper](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=583820) and [Wysoczanski's paper](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=934870) for details.
It is proved by Wysoczanski that a group $G$ is uniformly amenable if and only if
its ultrapower is amenable.
In particular solvable groups are uniformly amenable, while the locally finite group of finite permutations on a countable set is not.

Now, let's recall that a group $G$ is amenable at infinity (a.k.a. exact) if
for any finite subset $E\subset G$ and any $\epsilon>0$
there are a finite subset $F\subset G$ and a function $\eta\colon G\to\mathrm{Prob}(F)$ such that
$$\sup_{s\in E,\, x\in G} \|s\eta_x-\eta_{sx}\|_1 \le\epsilon.$$
Here $\mathrm{Prob}(F)$ is the space of probability measure on the finite set $F$,
viewed as a subset of $\ell_1(G)$.
For example, when $G$ is amenable, one can take $\eta_x=|F|^{-1}1_{F}$ for all $x\in G$.
As in the previous case, the group $G$ is said to be **uniformly amenable at infinity** (or **uniformly exact**) if one can find such $F$ and $\eta$ with $|F|\le \alpha(|E|,\epsilon)$.

> Are there interesting examples of groups that are uniformly amenable at infinity?

> In particular, are linear groups uniformly amenable at infinity?

It is proved by [Guentner–Higson–Weinberger](http://www.numdam.org/item/PMIHES_2005__101__243_0/) ([MathSciNet link](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=2217050)) that linear groups are amenable at infinity and so are their ultrapower. However, since the $\sup$ is the above definition is taken over an infinite set,
this doesn't imply (at least in a obvious way) that linear groups are uniformly amenable at infinity.
Still, I inclined to conjecture that linear groups are uniformly amenable at infinity.
Even the simplest case of the free groups looks very challenging.

Comment: Have you checked whether the ultraproduct characterization also works ($G$ uniformly exact iff $^\eta G$ is exact for some/every nonprincipal integral ultrafilter)? The result would indeed follow. In the case of amenability, the verification is pretty straightforward.

Comment: @Ycor Isn't your question answered in the last paragraph of the question?

Comment: @MikaeldelaSalle ah, thanks, indeed it seems to suggest it doesn't follow easily... And actually, if $S_{(\omega)}$ is the group of finitary permutations of $\omega$, its ultraproduct contains all countable residually finite groups if I'm correct. And there exists non-exact such groups, as proved by Osajda [ArXiv link](https://arxiv.org/abs/1703.03791).